# How do i join between 2 entities with column other than primary key using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables Employee and Address. Each have primary key **empId** and **addressId**  which is generated through sequence.

**Employee Class:**

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "sequence_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "emp_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "emp_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "emp_seq")
    private Long sequenceId;

    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private String empId;

    @Column(name = "joiningDate")
    private Date businessDate;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
}
```

**Address Class**

public class Address {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "address_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "address_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "address_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "address_seq")
private Long addressID;

@Column(name = "street")
private String street;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Employee employee;
```

}

I am using JPARepository to save both entities. here is my main class.

```
Employee e = Employee.builder().businessDate(new Date())
        .empId("thinkerId").build();
Address a = Address.builder().street("32nd Street")
        .employee(e).build();
e.setAddress(a);
empRepository.save(e);
```

Code runs successfully. But in my Address table, emp_Id column contains the primary key instead of the emp_id column.

How can i get **"thinkerId"** as value in Address table?

Thank you.

Comment: What about sharing the same Id with Employee ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Address` entity you must explicitly specify the column you are referring to:

```
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "address_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "address_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "address_seq")
    private Long addressID;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", referencedColumnName = "emp_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Employee employee;
}
```